# How to keep savory biscotti crunchy?

Tags: baking, texture

I've made several batches of [this recipe for savory biscotti](http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/parmesan-black-pepper-biscotti-236698). They are a pleasant crunchy texture after baking and cooling. The next day, after being stored in an airtight container, they are no longer crunchy! They are made with eggs, whole milk, and butter, and I'm wondering if the fat in those ingredients is why they lose their crunchiness. I like the richness that the fat provides. Any recommendations on how to keep them crunchy?

Comment: Were they really completely cooled before you put them in the airtight container?

Comment: @Jefromi Yes, completely cooled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll bet the rent that they weren't baked completely dry. Moisture made it to the crust overnight as happens with crunchy bread crust going leathery.

Comment: I will try this out. Maybe I'll increase the time during the cooler 2nd bake.

Comment: I tried baking them longer yesterday. This morning I tested them out...you are totally right! They are crisp and crunchy. (I increased the time of the second bake to 1.5 hours at 275 degrees F.) Thank you!

Comment: Great! It's safe to post the rent check